# How to replace String only Starting line with in VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

How replace a String with Starting line in the MS Word
example

```
The Statue of Liberty of New York was (a) gifted by which country?
(a) Britain
(b) France
(c) Germany
(d) Spain
```

Here (a) only need to replace with (A) which is Line Starting

output like

```
The Statue of Liberty of New York was (a) gifted by which country?
(A) Britain
(b) France
(c) Germany
(d) Spain
```

```vb
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "^\(a\)"
    .Replacement.Text = "(A)"
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchWildcards = True
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
```

Comment: have you written something we can look at? There are a few options you can consider like using a Regular Expression (recommend this) or look to go over your text

Comment: "*(a) only need to replace with (A)*". But you have also added spaces/tabs in your output. As well as the need to include code that you have tried, please make sure your question is consistent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code replaces all `(a)` at the beginning of the paragraph with `(A)`:

```
Sub ReplA()
    With ActiveDocument.Range
        .Find.Text = "(a)"
        Do While .Find.Execute
            If .Start = .Paragraphs(1).Range.Start Then .Text = "(A)"
        Loop
    End With
End Sub
```

**Before**

```
(a) first line
The Statue of Liberty of New York was (a) gifted by which country?
(a) Britain
(b) France
(c) Germany
(d) Spain (a)
(a) will also be changed
```

**After**

```
(A) first line
The Statue of Liberty of New York was (a) gifted by which country?
(A) Britain
(b) France
(c) Germany
(d) Spain (a)
(A) will also be changed
```